# Everything broken after removal of Amazon Search

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I have removed the Amazon lens and disabled the settings and since then I had an empty dash. I tried `unity --replace`, which killed everything.

I can understand that you want to make money with the distribution and I believe when you say that this is not something done on purpose but it leaves a pretty bad taste to it.

I want to actually use Ubuntu for my business but if Ubuntu is going the Microsoft way there is no need to change and I'll wait for the next distro to implement a deskop management system.

I will try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. If this isn't working I had it.

Comment: That's not a question. It's more like flaming about Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry this was part of my intention when I wrote it. I hope my answer makes it up. I think the way the dash was integrated with connections to Amazon and others provides nice funcionality and is understandable as people have to be paid that developed this great distro but to me it seems there are some privacy related issues. So my reaction was a little private too. I apologize for any inconvenience caused. As constructive feedback it would be great if users would be asked if they want to disable the functionality the first time the dash is opening.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get to Terminal then you will need to create a Desktop Launcher for the application.

Locate **usr/share/applications**, find the Terminal app and then copy and paste it to the **Desktop**.

1 - Open **Terminal**

2 - Copy & Paste Command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scopes-home
```

3 - Press **Enter**

4 - Enter Your Password When Prompted, Press **Enter** Again

Unity Scopes Home will now be reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it the following way:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get to the console

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This fixed the desktop but not the empty dash.

I installed unity-scope-home and unity-lens-shopping (it seems that with 13.10 unity-lens-shopping should not be removed any longer)

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-shopping
```

Then I was running following command to disable the spyware:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-   amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

I have disabled all the filters in the Unity dash and only left Applications and Local Files. I have checked with iftop if there are any outgoing connections when I search but there have been none. So the connections to third party providers were removed which was what I wanted.